# "fatal error : Failed to open output file" when compiling CUDA programs under Win 7

Tags: visual-studio, cuda, compiler-errors, windows-7-x64

whenever I try to compile a CUDA program (even the samples) on Windows 7 (64 Bit), using VisualStudio 2010 and CUDA 5.0, I get the error message below and nvcc crashes:

```
1>------ Erstellen gestartet: Projekt: vectorAdd, Konfiguration: Debug x64 ------
1>  Compiling CUDA source file vectorAdd.cu...
1>  
1>  C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v5.0\0_Simple\vectorAdd>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_10,code=\"sm_10,compute_10\" -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\" -gencode=arch=compute_30,code=\"sm_30,compute_30\" -gencode=arch=compute_35,code=\"sm_35,compute_35\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2010 -ccbin "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64"  -I"../../common/inc" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\include"  -G   --keep-dir "x64\Debug" -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile  -g   -DWIN32 -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Zi /RTC1 /MTd  " -o "x64/Debug/vectorAdd.cu.obj" "C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v5.0\0_Simple\vectorAdd\vectorAdd.cu" 
1>nvcc : fatal error : Failed to open output file 'C:\Users\<MY_USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Temp;"C:\Windows\winsxs"/tmpxft_00001d24_00000000'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 5.0.targets(592,9): error MSB3721: Der Befehl ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_10,code=\"sm_10,compute_10\" -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\" -gencode=arch=compute_30,code=\"sm_30,compute_30\" -gencode=arch=compute_35,code=\"sm_35,compute_35\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2010 -ccbin "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64"  -I"../../common/inc" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\include"  -G   --keep-dir "x64\Debug" -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile  -g   -DWIN32 -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Zi /RTC1 /MTd  " -o "x64/Debug/vectorAdd.cu.obj" "C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v5.0\0_Simple\vectorAdd\vectorAdd.cu"" wurde mit Code -1073741819 beendet.
========== Erstellen: 0 erfolgreich, Fehler bei 1, 0 aktuell, 0 übersprungen ==========
```

This error also occurs when I try to compile the program from the command line or using VS2008.
I have tried redownloading and reinstalling CUDA, the display driver and VisualStudio. The permissions for the Temp folder are set correctly.
I also tested the solutions proposed in these two threads:
https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/503284/?comment=3590464
https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/406549/?comment=2860913
Unfortunately, none of it worked :(

I am fairly new to CUDA, so maybe I just forgot a setting, but the target architectures were set to x64 for both host and device code, and in the samples the settings should be correct anyways.

If anyone knows a solutions to this problem I will be glad to hear it!

Kind regards,
maddin45

EDIT: formated the compiler output as code for better readability

Comment: Does the directory `C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v5.0\0_Simple\vectorAdd\x64\Debug` exist?  Is there already a file in it called `vectorAdd.cu.obj`?  If that file exists, can you manually delete it?

Comment: Hi, the directory exists, but there is no such file.

Comment: Did you modify any of the project paths?  When I compile that cuda 5 sample under VS 2008 using x64 project, I get a slightly different output path:  `-o "x64\Debug/vectorAdd.cu.obj"`

Comment: No, I just used the standard sample files. And as far as I can see I have the same output path set in the command line options of nvcc (the next-to-last attribute in the 4th line). Or did you mean something else?
I edited the compiler output so it is shown as code, so now the lines are displayed correctly :)

Comment: Ok sorry now I can see what is going on better.  My previous questions were not relevant.  The issue is with this path: `C:\Users\<MY_USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Temp;"C:\Windows\winsxs"/tmpxft_00001d24_00000000`  Did you put the `C:\Windows\winsxs` in your paths somewhere?   You may want to search around in your project settings for where that is appearing.

Comment: Thank you! That was the solution! The path `C:\Windows\winsxs` was added to the end of my user's TEMP variable. I removed it and now the samples compile without an error. Thank you very much for your support! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED
Thanks to the support of SO member Robert Crovella I was able to find the error. The path `"C:\Windows\winsxs"` was added to the end of my user's TEMP variable. I removed it and now the samples compile without an error.